# CSS; moving header logo in wordpress installation

Tags: css, wordpress

This should be simple, but I can't figure it out:

[Here is the site:](http://www.therunexperience.com/blog/)

I want the logo at the top to be brought down by 20px. I'm using chrome and trying to mod the CSS in the developer tool to figure out what is keeping it stuck to the top, but haven't figured it out yet. I thought the obvious answer would be to increase the padding-top, but nothing moves when I add that in.

Comment: Try adding margin and border too. Those should widen the padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Played around with your code.  Padding-top works, but on the div that contains your image - `class="head-wrap"`.  Just add `padding-top:20px;` to that element.  It worked in developer console for me.  Better than adding a margin to the `<header>` element as you won't reveal the body color.

full css you should be able to use

```
.head-wrap{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the site-header add `margin-top:20px;` The css would be:

```
.site-header {
    background: url(http://www.therunexperience.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/TRESimpleWhite_small4.png) no-repeat !important;
   margin-top: 20px;
}
```

EDIT:

Or for padding add:

```
.head-wrap 
{
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```